# R - Filtering datetimes that are less than a set of datetimes

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have two dataframes.

One is my `data` where I have several variable columns and several datetime related columns (datetimes, week #, dates, hour, minute, second), which has data for everyday in 2017. For example,

```
> glimpse(data)
Observations: 8,001,013
Variables: 12

$ id                 <chr> "(2, 3, 4)", "(5,)", "(6,)", "(7,)", "(8,)", "(9,)", "(10,)", "(11,)", "(12,)", "(13,)", "(14,)", "(15,)", "(16,)", "(17,)", "(18,)", "(19,)", "(20,)", "(21,...
$ x                  <int> 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1...
$ num                <chr> "set([4225])", "set([4712])", "set([5271])", "set([5334])", "set([5395])", "set([5658])", "set([5889])", "set([6020])", "set([6063])", "set([6090])", "set([6...
$ w                  <int> 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1...
$ z                  <int> 4, 6, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -2, 2, 7, 1, -3, -2, 1, -1, 3, 2, 3, -2, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, 4, 1, 2, -3, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3, 1, 1, 1...
$ datetime           <dttm> 2017-02-19 18:00:00, 2017-02-19 18:00:00, 2017-02-19 18:00:00, 2017-02-19 18:00:00, 2017-02-19 18:00:00, 2017-02-19 18:00:01, 2017-02-19 18:00:01, 2017-02-1...
$ date               <date> 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-19, ...
$ day_of_week        <ord> Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Sun, Su...
$ week               <dbl> 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8...
$ hour               <int> 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 1...
$ minute             <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ second             <dbl> 0.1187501, 0.3406179, 0.7030604, 0.7431633, 0.7939658, 1.0090485, 1.1624568, 1.2924566, 1.3619752, 1.3922081, 1.4920712, 1.5121725, 1.5621316, 1.6688271, 1.7...
```

The other dataframe is simply a small list of 8 key datetimes, `key_datetimes`, e.g.

```
> key_datetimes
# A tibble: 9 x 2
         Code         keyDateTime
        <chr>               <chr>
1       TAIL1 2017-01-12 08:30:00
2       TAIL2 2017-02-09 11:40:00
3       TAIL3 2017-03-22 08:30:01
4       TAIL4 2017-04-13 10:30:00
5       TAIL5 2017-05-19 08:30:00
6       TAIL6 2017-06-13 08:35:00
7       TAIL7 2017-07-28 09:30:00
8       TAIL8 2017-08-23 06:30:00
9       TAIL9 2017-09-13 07:30:00
```

I want to label the data for each week up to the specific datetimes in `key_datetimes`. So I want to create a new column in `data` called `before_key_datetime` that is TRUE if `data$datetime < key_datetimes` otherwise FALSE.

How can I accomplish this?

In other words, I want to do is keep just the weeks of interest (this works), then I group by each week (this works) then for each group label/mutate a new column that says which rows are before/after the keyDateTime from the second dataframe (can't get this part).

Things I have tried:

- Doing an `ifelse` on one datetime works.
- Doing an `ifelse` vector to vector obviously doesn't vector:
  `data %>% filter(week %in% lubridate::week(as.Date(key_datetimes$keyDateTime))) %>% group_by(week) %>%  filter(datetime %in%  c(as.POSIXct(key_datetimes$keyDateTime)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is what you want, but try using `zoo::na.locf` after merging your key with your data and arranging by Date

To fill in **before** each key date

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  full_join(key, by="Date") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Code, key), funs(zoo::na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=TRUE)))
```

Output (head)

```
                   Date Code   key
1   2017-01-02 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
2   2017-01-03 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
3   2017-01-04 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
4   2017-01-05 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
5   2017-01-06 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
6   2017-01-07 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
7   2017-01-08 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
8   2017-01-09 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
```

**simpler example**

```
simple <- head(df)
ans <- simple %>%
  full_join(key, by="Date") %>%
  arrange(Date)
```

I left out the last `mutate_at` step. The full_join is only meant to combine data from both (without losing data). All the data from `simple` and `key` are still present in the output. The point is to combine all the data and then sort them. This is an easy way to see the order of entries.

```
                  Date Code   key
1  2017-01-02 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
2  2017-01-03 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
3  2017-01-04 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
4  2017-01-05 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
5  2017-01-06 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
6  2017-01-07 00:00:01   NA  <NA>    # from simple
7  2017-01-12 08:30:00    1 TAIL1    # from key
8  2017-02-09 11:40:00    2 TAIL2
9  2017-03-22 08:30:01    3 TAIL3
10 2017-04-13 10:30:00    4 TAIL4
11 2017-05-19 08:30:00    5 TAIL5
12 2017-06-13 08:35:00    6 TAIL6
13 2017-07-28 09:30:00    7 TAIL7
14 2017-08-23 06:30:00    8 TAIL8
15 2017-09-13 07:30:00    9 TAIL9
```

The `mutate_at` will fill in all `NA`s with the nearest value traveling backwards. So Code and key in rows 1-6 will take on values in row 7.

**You can now use the Code or key to filter for Dates that you are interested in OR determine whether a Date in your full data frame is before a key date**. For instance,

```
ans <- df %>%
  full_join(key, by="Date") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Code, key), funs(zoo::na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=TRUE)))
```

To find dates that are before key[1,] `1 TAIL1 2017-01-12 08:30:00`, you can do

```
ans %>%
   filter(Code==1)
# The last row is from your key data frame
```

Or

```
ans %>%
   filter(key=="TAIL1")
```

To determine if a date in your data frame is before a key date,

```
ans[3, ]
#                  Date Code   key
# 3 2017-01-04 00:00:01    1 TAIL1
```

Tells you the 3rd entry in your data frame is before key[1,] `1 TAIL1 2017-01-12 08:30:00`

#### just in case

To fill in **after** each key Date

```
df %>%
  full_join(key, by="Date") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Code, key), funs(zoo::na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=FALSE)))
```

Output (tail)

```
363 2017-12-21 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
364 2017-12-22 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
365 2017-12-23 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
366 2017-12-24 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
367 2017-12-25 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
368 2017-12-26 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
369 2017-12-27 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
370 2017-12-28 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
371 2017-12-29 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
372 2017-12-30 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
373 2017-12-31 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
374 2018-01-01 00:00:01    9 TAIL9
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Date = ymd_hms("2017-01-01 00:00:01") + days(x=1:365))

key <- structure(list(Code = 1:9, key = c("TAIL1", "TAIL2", "TAIL3", 
"TAIL4", "TAIL5", "TAIL6", "TAIL7", "TAIL8", "TAIL9"), Date = structure(c(1484209800, 
1486640400, 1490171401, 1492079400, 1495182600, 1497342900, 1501234200, 
1503469800, 1505287800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Code", "key", 
"Date"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I don't want to fill in anything. I simply want to know if a datetime is before or after a another datetime (i.e. `key_datetime` in my question). Your answer seems to be adding rows.

Comment: You can filter for those datetimes that are before your key using my approach above. I've edited my answer to indicate this.

Comment: The problem is I cannot do the initial join by date because these are date times to the second level and there is not necessarily and exact one to join on between the two data frames.

Comment: I am also confused by the `mutate_at` line, what is this doing exactly?

Comment: @tbone See my updated answer with a simpler example showing what the join is for and what the `mutate_at` is doing

Comment: Glad my explanation helped you out.

Comment: Any idea how to join the datetimes?

Comment: To join datestimes, you'll need to add the datestimes in your key to the full data. Note that the key values after merge will always be the last entry of each group. You can always filter out the key values using something like `head(...,-1)`

Comment: I have datetimes in both, but I can't join two things if the values aren't equal. In my full data set, I don't have datetimes at every second of the day.....

Comment: Please look again at the simple example. Note that datetimes were not common in `simple` and `key`. You can keep all of the data from both even if they do not match.